# Gmail API messages.insert vs messages.import

Tags: gmail-api

In the Gmail REST API there are two methods that seem to do the same thing:

messages.insert and messages.import

What is the difference between these two methods and under what circumstances should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are similar in that they are both a way to get an email message into the authenticated user's mailbox (not sending).  Insert is the functional equivalent of IMAP APPEND (fast, no categorization and allows specifying labelIds).   Whereas import is like receiving over SMTP and seems more geared for bulk email migration use cases, where labels are applied based on normal delivery-time categorization.  See: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import